# Display form fields for nested attributes by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I'm trying to build a form with nested attributes and in my view `views/pedidos/new.html.erb` I want to display one group of fields to **pessoa** and one to **produto** by default. In my **PedidosController** I have used `pessoa = @pedido.build_pessoa` and it works perfectly, my form render **pessoa** fields, but for **produto** I tried `produto = @pedido.build_produtos` and it says `undefined method 'build_produtos' for #<Pedido id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>`

Here's my models and my controller (used scaffold to generate)

```
class Pedido < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :pessoa_attributes, :produtos_attributes

  has_one :pessoa
  has_many :produtos

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pessoa, :produtos, allow_destroy: true
end

class Pessoa < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :nome, :telefone

  belongs_to :pedido
end

class Produto < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :nome, :quantidade

  belongs_to :pedido
end

class PedidosController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @pedido = Pedido.new
    1.times do
      pessoa = @pedido.build_pessoa
      produto = @pedido.build_produtos
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @pedido }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the relationship is `has_many`, you build it like so: `@pedido.produtos.build`

For a `has_one` is prefixed as you've done, with `build_[association]`.

Kindof a gotchya, but simple once you know what's going on.